# How can the edge colors of individual matplotlib histograms be set?

Tags: matplotlib, colors, histogram

I've got a rough and ready function that can be used to compare two sets of values using histograms:

[image]

I want to set the individual edge colors of each of the histograms in the top plot (much as how I set the individual sets of values used for each histogram). How could this be done?

```
import os

import datavision
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy
import shijian

def main():

    a = numpy.random.normal(2, 2, size = 120)
    b = numpy.random.normal(2, 2, size = 120)

    save_histogram_comparison_matplotlib(
        values_1      = a,
        values_2      = b,
        label_1       = "a",
        label_2       = "b",
        normalize     = True,
        label_ratio_x = "measurement",
        label_y       = "",
        title         = "comparison of a and b",
        filename      = "histogram_comparison_1.png"
    )

def save_histogram_comparison_matplotlib(
    values_1       = None,
    values_2       = None,
    filename       = None,
    directory      = ".",
    number_of_bins = None,
    normalize      = True,
    label_x        = "",
    label_y        = None,
    label_ratio_x  = None,
    label_ratio_y  = "ratio",
    title          = "comparison",
    label_1        = "1",
    label_2        = "2",
    overwrite      = True,
    LaTeX          = False,
    #aspect         = None,
    font_size      = 20,
    color_1        = "#3861AA",
    color_2        = "#00FF00",
    color_3        = "#7FDADC",
    color_edge_1   = "#3861AA", # |<---------- insert magic for these
    color_edge_2   = "#00FF00", # |
    alpha          = 0.5,
    width_line     = 1
    ):

    matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()
    if LaTeX is True:
        matplotlib.pyplot.rc("text", usetex = True)
        matplotlib.pyplot.rc("font", family = "serif")
    if number_of_bins is None:
        number_of_bins_1 = datavision.propose_number_of_bins(values_1)
        number_of_bins_2 = datavision.propose_number_of_bins(values_2)
        number_of_bins   = int((number_of_bins_1 + number_of_bins_2) / 2)
    if filename is None:
        if title is None:
            filename = "histogram_comparison.png"
        else:
            filename = shijian.propose_filename(
                filename  = title + ".png",
                overwrite = overwrite
            )
    else:
        filename = shijian.propose_filename(
            filename  = filename,
            overwrite = overwrite
        )

    values = []
    values.append(values_1)
    values.append(values_2)
    bar_width = 0.8
    figure, (axis_1, axis_2) = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(
        nrows       = 2,
        gridspec_kw = {"height_ratios": (2, 1)}
    )
    ns, bins, patches = axis_1.hist(
        values,
        color     = [
                        color_1,
                        color_2
                    ],
        normed    = normalize,
        histtype  = "stepfilled",
        bins      = number_of_bins,
        alpha     = alpha,
        label     = [label_1, label_2],
        rwidth    = bar_width,
        linewidth = width_line,
        #edgecolor = [color_edge_1, color_edge_2] <---------- magic here? dunno
    )
    axis_1.legend(
        loc = "best"
    )
    bars = axis_2.bar(
        bins[:-1],
        ns[0] / ns[1],
        alpha     = 1,
        linewidth = 0, #width_line
        width     = bins[1] - bins[0]
    )
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_color(color_3)
    axis_1.set_xlabel(label_x, fontsize = font_size)
    axis_1.set_ylabel(label_y, fontsize = font_size)
    axis_2.set_xlabel(label_ratio_x, fontsize = font_size)
    axis_2.set_ylabel(label_ratio_y, fontsize = font_size)
    #axis_1.xticks(fontsize = font_size)
    #axis_1.yticks(fontsize = font_size)
    #axis_2.xticks(fontsize = font_size)
    #axis_2.yticks(fontsize = font_size)
    matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle(title, fontsize = font_size)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    #if aspect is None:
    #    matplotlib.pyplot.axes().set_aspect(
    #        1 / matplotlib.pyplot.axes().get_data_ratio()
    #    )
    #else:
    #    matplotlib.pyplot.axes().set_aspect(aspect)
    figure.tight_layout()
    matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust(top = 0.9)
    matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(
        directory + "/" + filename,
        dpi = 700
    )
    matplotlib.pyplot.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the lists of `Patches` objects returned by the `hist()` function.

In your case, you have two datasets, so your variable `patches` will be a list containing two lists, each with the `Patches` objects used to draw the bars on your plot.

You can easily set the properties on all of these objects using the `setp()` function. For example:

```
a = np.random.normal(size=(100,))
b = np.random.normal(size=(100,))
c,d,e = plt.hist([a,b], color=['r','g'])
plt.setp(e[0], edgecolor='k', lw=2)
plt.setp(e[1], edgecolor='b', lw=3)
```

Comment: This works but if I set `alpha=0.5` to the original hist, it also gets applied to the edges. Trying to override that by passing `alpha=1.0` to `setp` changes the alpha value of the original histogram.

Answer (score 3):

You may simply plot two different histograms but share the bins.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(3)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.random.normal(size=(89,2))

kws = dict(histtype= "stepfilled",alpha= 0.5, linewidth = 2)
hist, edges,_ = plt.hist(a[:,0], bins = 6,color="lightseagreen", label = "A", edgecolor="k", **kws)
plt.hist(a[:,1], bins = edges,color="gold", label = "B",  edgecolor="crimson", **kws)

plt.show()
```

[image]